# Perform simple queries in Cloud Firestore - how can i filter all through select?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, dynamic-queries, next.js13

I need to to filter data through queries from Firestore, but how can I also get all of them(in my case all states in firestore)? What should be useState value in this case? I'm a newbie :) Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

```
//WHAT useState VALUE SHOULD I USE TO GET ALL STATES IN DATABASE?
const (city, setCity) = useState("CA");

const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");
const q = query(citiesRef, where("state", "==", city));
```

Tried to search in firestore docs and google.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `getDocs()` method provided by firebase as follows

here, `q` is your query ( `const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where(....)`);

add following code -

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
});
```

[you can refer to this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)

Answer (score 1):

As you wanted to use `useState`, You can pass an empty string `” “` or `Null` value  and use `!=` instead of `=` operator in the where clause.
And use [getDocs()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) to retrieve all documents  as mentioned by @Prathmesh

Here is the complete code:

```
const [city, setCity] = useState(" ");

const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");
const q = query(citiesRef, where("state", "!=", city));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I thought there is just some value i could use for all cities in the database.